# Constructor not working when using Integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to create a simple program that an object that has an Integer Array as it's member and a method toString() that prints out all the elements in the Array. The code look like this:

```
public final class IntegerArray {

      private int a[];

      IntegerArray(int a[])
      {
          for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) this.a[i]=a[i];
      }

      public String toString()
      {
          String fin=new String();
          fin+='[';
          for(int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++)
          {
              fin+=a[i]+", ";
          }
          fin+=a[a.length-1];
          fin+=']';
          return fin;
      }
}

public class IntegerArrayTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random=new Random();

        int[] a={1, 5, 3, 7};
        IntegerArray A=new IntegerArray(a);
        System.out.println(A.toString());

    }

}
```

However when I run the program it gives me 2 errors. One in the constructor and another when I initialize an the object from the class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at main.IntegerArray.<init>(IntegerArray.java:9)

    at main.IntegerArrayTester.main(IntegerArrayTester.java:14)
```

Can somebody please tell what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `this.a[i]` is the problem, you don't initialise the array first...

Comment: dont loop through, you just need to assign it to. `this.a = a;` easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize array in `IntegerArray` constructor like this:

```
IntegerArray(int a[])
{
  this.a = new int[a.length];
  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) this.a[i]=a[i];
}
```

Also, you can assign `this.a = a`, but if you do it, any operation with `this.a` array in your class, such as remove, add or edit element, array `a` will be change too, because operation `this.a = a` you just make a "link" to `a` and work with original `a` array.

Comment: Thank you very. That seem to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You array isn't initialitazed, so it gives a NullpointerException, you should add this in the constructor:

```
        this.a=new int[a.length];
```

So it ends as:

```
    IntegerArray(int a[]) {
                this.a=new int[a.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                    this.a[i] = a[i];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `a[]` in `IntegerArray`

```
public final class IntegerArray {

    private int a[]; // here it's null
    ...
}
```

You should initialize the class variable creating a new array about the size of the one you are receiving as parameter:

```
 public final class IntegerArray {

     private int a[]; // here it's null

     IntegerArray(int a[]){
         this.a = new int[a.length];
         ...
     }
}
```

And by the way you don't have to loop over the array. You can just clone it:

```
 public final class IntegerArray {

     private int a[];

     IntegerArray(int a[]){
        this.a = a.clone();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## What is the issue

You do not initialise a, so it is equal to null

## Why is this an issue

You cannot call methods on null, as that causes NullPointerExceptions

## How to fix

You need to initialise the array before you use it, an example of how would be:

```
this.a=new int[a.length];
```